# modified base number conversion

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I'm having a mental block trying to make a modified
  number base convertor.

What I have works correctly, however I want the output
  to be padded with 0'th character of the base I am using.

For example if I use base 3

```
int n,v;
char txt[100];
for(n=0;n<5;n++)
{
    ToBase(3,n,txt);
    FromBase(3,&v,txt);
    printf("\n m=%u txt=[%s] i=%u",n,txt,v);
}
```

Output:

```
 m=0 txt=[A] i=0
 m=1 txt=[B] i=1
 m=2 txt=[C] i=2
 m=3 txt=[BA] i=3
 m=4 txt=[BB] i=4
 m=5 txt=[BC] i=5
 m=6 txt=[CA] i=6
 m=7 txt=[CB] i=7
 m=8 txt=[CC] i=8
 m=9 txt=[BAA] i=9
```

The output I need is:

```
 m=0 txt=[A] i=0
 m=1 txt=[B] i=1
 m=2 txt=[C] i=2
 m=3 txt=[AA] i=3
 m=4 txt=[AB] i=4
 m=5 txt=[AC] i=5
 m=6 txt=[BA] i=6
 m=7 txt=[BB] i=7
 m=8 txt=[BC] i=8
 m=9 txt=[CA] i=9
```

Here are the functions:

```
void ToBase(int base,int num,void* str)
{
    char * tbl="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char buf[66] = {'\0'};
    char * out;
    int n;
    int i,len=0,neg=0;

    if(base>26)
        oof;

    n = ((neg = num < 0)) ? (~num) + 1 : num;
    do {
        buf[len++] = tbl[n % base];
    } while(n /= base);

    out=(char*)str;
    for (i = neg; len > 0; i++)
        out[i] = buf[--len];
}


void FromBase(int base,int* num,void* str)
{
    int i,d,n,sl;
    char*bp;
    bp=(char*)str;
    sl=strlen(bp);
    i=0;
    for(n=0;n<sl;n++)
    {
        i*=base;
        if(bp[n]>='A'&&bp[n]<='Z')
            d=(bp[n]-'A');
        else if(bp[n]>='a'&&bp[n]<='z')
            d=(bp[n]-'a');
        i+=d;
    }
    *num=i;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated -

Comment: please fix your indentation. And, please outline what exactly you mean by "base calculator".

Comment: conversion of one number base to another - if ToBase is called with the first arg as 16 , then Hex would be output, if the arg was 2, then binary etc -

Comment: Obviously, there's a problem with either `ToBase` or `FromBase` (or both) since your computed value of `txt` isn't what you want. Equally obviously, nobody is going to be able to help you unless you show us what's going on in `ToBase` and `FromBase`. Perhaps not as obviously: your post makes no sense. You say that you are computing things correctly and the problem is padding, yet you show no padding and the output seems wrong.

Comment: Protip: Bases less than ten can be written using only numerals, and `0` can always represent zero.

Comment: This function - is to be used for a domain crawler - ( letters only ) - and I want to convert a domain name <> a number e.g a.com z.com aa.com az.com ba.com etc

Comment: @AshodApakian OK, answered… but in that case, why pad with zeroes and fix the length? That introduces a new variable for the name length. If you don't pad, the magnitude of the number alone determines the length. (You can get the length from the index number using `floor(log(n)/log(base))`.)

Comment: Is anyone else *dying* to see what `oof` is ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a feature so it knows how many characters to output. Just making a minimal change:

```
     void ToBase                 (int base,int num,void* str,int min_length)
      {
      char * tbl="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      char buf[66] = {'\0'};
      char * out;
      int n;
      int i,len=0,neg=0;
      if(base>26) oof; /* is a macro? perhaps use assert() */
      n = ((neg = num < 0)) ? (~num) + 1 : num;
      do { buf[len++] = tbl[n % base]; } while(n /= base||--min_length>0);
      out=(char*)str;
      for (i = neg; len > 0; i++) out[i] = buf[--len];
      }
```

Comment: :) yes oof; is my macro that calls MessageBox();

Comment: @AshodApakian Usually we write `assert(base>26)`. You can `#undef assert` and `#define assert(x) do { if(x) oof; } while(0)` if you want to migrate to a more portable coding practice…

Comment: oof - actually calls a whole bunch of profiling macros , which are far to intertwined at this point in time - current length of the overall file is a hair of 55k lines - sorry for weird snippet

Comment: @AshodApakian Actually more reason to make such a change… `assert` is part of the mechanism that most IDEs and build systems tell you whether you're building in debug or release mode. If you control `oof` using `#ifndef NDEBUG`, then you can strip that profiling stuff from the final product. How complicated `oof` is doesn't matter, as long as it doesn't change what the program does.

Answer (score 0):

In `ToBase` switch this:

```
do { buf[len++] = tbl[n % base]; } while(n /= base);
```

with this:

```
do { buf[len++] = tbl[n % base]; n = (n/base) - 1; } while(n >= 0);
```